# Numerator of Sample Variance Expectation

Tags: probability, statistics, summation

Suppose $w_1, \dots, w_k$ are iid with mean $\mu_w$, variance $\sigma^2_w$.

I understand the proof that 
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^{k}(w_i-\bar{w}_{\cdot})^2\right] = (k-1)\sigma^2_w$$
where $\bar{w}_{\cdot} = \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^{k}w_i}{k}$.

Suppose $u_{ij} \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2_u)$ for $i = 1, \dots, t$ and $j = 1, \dots n$ are iid. I'm not sure how to see that 
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^{t}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left(u_{ij}-\bar{u}_{i\cdot}\right)^2\right] = t(n-1)\sigma^2_u\text{.}$$
How I thought of this is that there are $tn$ $u_{ij}$ terms, so the expected value should be $$(tn-1)\sigma^2_u$$
but this doesn't match with what I have in these notes.

If it turns out that this is wrong, I'll delete this question and post a new question with more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pull the sum over $i$ out of the expectation using linearity and then use your previous result. You get a sum of $t$ copies of the same number, which gives the multiplication by $t$.

Your idea would be correct if instead of $\overline{u}_i$ you had $\overline{u}$ (averaged over *all* $(i,j)$).